# Grouping MySQL data by which day of the week it is

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to separate my database entries into the number of entries that fall on each day of the week (Mon=43, Tue=35...) with no regard for month or year. The result from the query below return eight results instead of seven and the number of results for each day is incorrect.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(date)
```

Example of my table:

```
date
07/11/13
07/16/13
07/17/13
07/24/13
07/26/13
07/26/13
```

Am I using DAYOFWEEK correctly?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: I get eight results with incorrect amounts when run on actual table.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted... I stated the question along with my code and what was going wrong when I ran the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to change your query as follow:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(date), COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(date)
```

so you can better understand if there's something wrong, anyway: yes you're using dayofweek correctly.
I am a bit surprised by the fact that you get 8 results... can you show us the results please?

Gnagno

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It actually appears that it is my date format the is the problem. I changed it to another format and I'm getting seven results with correct numbers.

Comment: side note : a null datetime can result in a 8th result too